# CSV seek to top not using file

Tags: python, csv, seek

I have a nested for loop and reading from two CSVs. How to seek to beginning of document when I have a reference to the reader and not the file.

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(stdout.decode('ascii').split('\n'), delimiter=' ')
for row in csv_reader:
  for r in csv_reader2:
    #do something
  #seek(0)
```

Comment: I don't think you can `reader` objects are 'C'-level objects and don't expose a reference to the underlying file object.

Answer (score 0):

in the for loop itself you can access them
keep a stop condition on loop count to cotrol loop execution

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(stdout.decode('ascii').split('\n'), delimiter=' ')

for row in csv_reader:
  for r in csv_reader2:
     print(f'{row} from 1, {r} from 2')
```